# How to get the total of grouped items on polymorphic column type in rails 5.0?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

The backgroud:

```
create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "imageable_id"
  t.string   "imageable_type"
  ...
end

class PrivateGallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class NationalGallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I want to do a simple query to get a hash of imageable_type and the count of rows with that type - `Image.group(:imageable_type).count`, but it returns:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "images"."imageable_type" AS images_imageable_type FROM "images" GROUP BY "images"."imageable_type" ORDER BY id ASC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "images.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...mages" GROUP BY "images"."imageable_type" ORDER BY id ASC
```

**EDIT:**

The question was how to make it work using Rails 5.

Works with reorder:

`Image.group(:imageable_type).reorder(:imageable_type).count`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "images"."imageable_type" AS images_imageable_type 
FROM "images" GROUP BY "images"."imageable_type" 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: This query works,great! but is there a way to make it work with ActiveRecord?

Comment: Basically what you are doing wrong is ordering your results based on `id`, which is not a part of list of columns getting selected in the result. So you are getting error in group by part. To resolve this, either add id in group by as well or use order by with one of the result columns